# Does anyone know of issues with jQuery selector in IE with html select boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following jQuery code for getting the first character of the string value of the selected option of an html select box.

```
var mode = $("#mode :selected").text()[0];
```

"mode" is the id of the html select element I want.  This is not working in IE at the moment - does anyone know why that might be?

EDIT:  Sorry everyone, it was nothing to do with jQuery.  IE just wanted

```
var mode = $("#mode :selected").text().charAt(0);
```

I'm not sure why I thought the [0] would work in the first place.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem is with not specifying the 'option'

we use this code in several of our projects and this does work in IE

```
$("#ComboBox option:selected").text()
```